# Adding event listener to button without using class or id property?

Tags: jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>css demo</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('button').on('click', function(){
            console.log("Day button clicked");
        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> My WebSite</h1>
    <div>
        <button data-file="day">Day</button>
        <button data-file2="night">Night</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just started learning jQuery, so forgive me my questions are vague or not of enough class. Is there anyway i can achieve separate clicks for Day and Night button without using **ID** or **Class** property.

I want to know if we can achieve the clicks collecting the data-file attribute [**using either attr or data property**].

Comment: `$('button[data-file="day"]')` will work.

Comment: The point here being: You can use **any** selector that will match, including an attribute selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target the two different data attributes :

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('button[data-file]').on('click', function(){ // or [data-file="day"] to be
        console.log("Day button clicked");         // even more specific
    });

    $('button[data-file2]').on('click', function(){
        console.log("Night button clicked");
    })
});
```